# Why do I get an undefined method when calling model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model with the following method

```
 class Legacy::Retailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :retailers
  self.table_name = 'orim_retailers'

  def retailer_options
    retailers = Array.new
    self.display_name.each do |names|
      retailers << names
    end
  end

end
```

When I try to call this method from the controller as

```
@retailer_options = Legacy::Retailer.retailer_options
```

I get a method an undefined method error.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you defined an instance method, not a class method.

To be able to call

```
Legacy::Retailer.retailer_options
```

you should define a class method:

```
  def self.retailer_options # note self here
    retailers = Array.new
    self.display_name.each do |names|
      retailers << names
    end
  end
```

And if you've meant to call this method on instances, not class itself, you should be able to do the following:

```
Legacy::Retailer.new.retailer_options
```

Answer (score 1):

The method retailer_options was defined as an instance method, and you are calling a class method. Take a look at the following code:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def baz
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end
```

If you call:

```
Foo.bar # => "class method"
Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class
```

And for the instance method:

```
Foo.new.baz # => instance method
Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar’ for #<Foo:0x1e820>
```

Hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

you've defined an instance method but you're calling it as a class method.

```
@retailer = Legacy::Retailer.new
@retailer.retailer_options
```

will work